# Can mobile login have an e-mail-specific keyboard?

Tags: feature-request, login, openid, mobile-web, mobile-safari

Facebook's usernames are typically e-mail addresses; Stack Exchange's OpenID usernames are AFAICT always e-mail addresses.

In Safari for iOS (7.0.4), the username field on Facebook's login page brings up the usual (English QWERTY, in my settings) keypad but with extra commercial at (`@`) and period (`.`) buttons to facilitate entry of an e-mail address:

[image: (screenshot)]

On the other hand, the username field on Stack Exchange's OpenID login page doesn't have those extra buttons:

[image: (screenshot)]

Can it, please?

Comment: This would actually be very easy to do by changing the input's type to `email` from `text` - any browser that supports it would show the email-layout keyboard. Past that, there's not really anything else SE can do to display a different keyboard more suited to emails.

Comment: @animuson I figured it must be something in the `input` tag, but iOS Safari doesn't allow me to see the source code (AFAIK), so I wasn't sure.

Comment: @animuson That is the only thing we need to change - mobile browsers will look out for that and pop out the email-optimized keyboard instead of the regular text one.